# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "patatús"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Una manera coloquial de decir que alguien se desmayó es "le dio un patatús". La palabra tiene una entrada en el DLE:

> [**patatús**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S8EAINH)
>
> De *pata*.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Desmayo, lipotimia.

Buscando sobre el origen de la palabra me encontré con las siguientes cosas.

De acuerdo a [esta página](http://365palabras.blogspot.com.co/2012/04/patatus.html) el origen es onomatopéyico:

> Con ella designamos un súbito desmayo. Es una palabra onomatopéyica, es decir, que reproduce el sonido de la persona que cae inconsciente al suelo.

La verdad no termino de relacionar el sonido de alguien que cae con la palabra patatús, pero digamos que sea un posible origen. Aunque le veo más sentido a la imagen que se usa para describir el término en esa misma página:

### [image]

La imagen la veo más relacionada con la información en el DLE que dice que viene de "pata" y relacionando pata con los pies que es lo que se ve en la imagen

> [**pata**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM%7CS72dH32)
>
> De *or. inc.*
>
> 1. f. Pie y pierna de los animales.
> 2. f. Pie de un mueble.
> 3. f. En las prendas de vestir, cartera, golpe.
> 4. f. coloq. Pierna de una persona.

Ahora, en otra parte me encontré el documento [Enciclopedia Etimológica Académica](http://www.radioverdad.org/system/files/Dic-et-2_Nombres_e_Hipocoristicos_0.pdf)  donde dice:

> **Patatús**: Ver Patatuz

y para Patatuz

> **Patatuz, el** : Del vulg. *pata= pie, pierna*.
>
> Patudo. Personaje que representa a la muerte

Quizá podría tener sentido al asociar el "desmayo" con la muerte. Buscando otra relación entre el "Patudo" y muerte encontré [el texto](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=ADtKAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA429&lpg=PA429&dq=Patudo%20muerte&source=bl&ots=5O548mu204&sig=geC99VRUhrdkenFHpXwer_k2I9M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibsvK7mMHXAhUC7SYKHUXwBPEQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=Patudo%20muerte&f=false) (Antología de la literatura española. Renacimiento y siglo de oro, Bárbara Mujica)

> *Diabo.*
>
> Patudo, ve muy saltando,
>
> llámame la Muerte acá;
>
> dile que ando navegando,
>
> y que la estoy esperando,
>
> que luego se volverá

Por último, [otra página](http://porqueledicen.blogspot.com.co)  vincula la palabra con un ritual religioso llamado "Patatú" pero no quedo muy convencido.

En fin, las explicaciones divergen mucho. ¿Hay alguna correcta? ¿Es otro el origen de la palabra "patatús"?

Comment: No encuentro nada concluyente. Aunque me resulta curioso que este parece el primer caso que encuentro en el que la palabra aparece en el DLE (1803) antes que en el CORDE (c1830) o la hemeroteca del BNE (1812). Yo me inclino a pensar que se formó a partir de voces similares como "pataplús", "pataplum" o "patapum", de las cuales hay registros por las mismas fechas indicadas (1822 para "pataplús").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay quien habla de su origen francés, en concreto en la entrada [*¿Por qué a la gente “le da un patatús”?*](http://porqueledicen.blogspot.com.es/):

> (...) la palabra *patapouf* (pronunciada por alguien que sepa francés) y la palabra patatús (pronunciada por cualquier hijo de vecina) suenan casi igual y significan cosas parecidas.
>
> El uso más común dado en el francés a *patapouf* es como adjetivo que describe a una persona típicamente del sexo masculno que es muy gordo, mafleta o regordete. Pero esta palabra es también usada como sinónimo de *patatrás*, vocablo también francés de origen onomatopéyico, que usa en el contexto de una caída aparatosa (...)

Si bien luego enfrían la hipótesis y sugieren otra:

> ¿Entonces, qué tan probable es que patatús sea un galicismo?
>
> En lo que a muchos de nosotros respecta, los franceses no tuvieron ninguna influencia en nuestra cultura hispana. Yo soy de los que lo único que saben decir en francés es “se la vi” y “Yo no compro pan”, pero  la realidad es que cuando uno se pone a ver, los franceses siempre tuvieron una influencia importante en Europa, incluidos los Españoles antes y durante su ocupación de Suramérica. En la edad media la influencia gala fue más en lo político, militar y cultural, y ya en los siglos XVII y XVIII todo lo francés, incluido el idioma,  se volvió sinónimo de prestigio y se puso de moda. Es posible que los españoles de la alta sociedad hayan usado patapouf al referirse a las caídas o desmayos y lo hayan puesto de moda, así como los Mayameros pusieron de moda tantos anglicismos en la época del ta’ barato dame dos, como por ejemplo: “pana”, que proviene fonéticamente “partner”: compañero, amigo, socio.
>
> Otra teoría mucho más plausible e interesante es la siguiente. Existe un ritual religioso antiguo, que data del siglo XVI -y quizás más atrás- el cual en Obejo Córdoba, España  se llama “patatú”. El Patatú de Obejo, es una danza con espadas, bastante elaborada y llena de simbolismos en donde se pedía al padre o patrono San Benito que trajera lluvia. En la actualidad, se mantiene la tradición en Obejo para dar comienzo a las romerías de San Benito Abad, pero en la antigüedad, en muchas partes de Europa y del mundo, se realizaban rituales muy similares y con el mismo motivo, usando también lanzas, palos o arcos (en lugar de espadas), y  con otros santos de protagonistas. Estas danzas de lanzas o espadas en honor a los santos, solían ocurrir el día de San Antón 17 de Enero, el de San Benito 11 de Julio, o el de San Juan 24 de Junio, pero también en cualquier otro momento del año en el que el agua estaba escasa.

Answer (score 0):

Patatús es un conjunto de palabras mayas que significa una muerte fingida, un desmayo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuetas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Yo noto cierto parentesco con la palabra "pataleta" (RAE: Convulsión, especialmente cuando se cree que es fingida)y otras como dijeron arriba de pataleos, "estirar la pata" (RAE: morir), "patitieso" (RAE:  Dicho de una persona: Que, por un accidente repentino, o por frío, se queda sin sentido ni movimiento en las piernas o pies). El "ús" me recuerda a "repelús" (RAE: Temor indefinido o repugnancia que inspira algo.)

Answer (score 0):

En las comunidades centroamericanas que hablaban la lengua *náhuatl*, **patatús** se usaba con el significado de "muerte fingida", y también para "desmayo".

Fuente: [Gran Diccionario etimológico Nahuatl - Universidad Autónoma de México](http://www.gdn.unam.mx/termino/search?queryCreiterio=ahuacatl&modulo=termino&action=search&queryEnDiccionarios%5B%5D=0&queryPartePalabra=inicio&queryBuscarEn=nahuatlGrafiaNormalizada&queryLimiteRegistros=200)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Patatús está relacionado al desmayo, con temblores o pataleos de los pies, indicando agonía o entrada al estado de gravedad.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido/a a la comunidad! En tu respuesta mencionas algo que ya se mencionó previamente en la pregunta. Lo que ésta busca es el origen de la palabra y no su significado, que ya es sabido.